# Workbench upsert: how to use an External id?

Tags: workbench, upsert, externalid

I want to update a number of Cases using a CSV file that contains two fields: case number (NOT technical id, but the automatically generated human readable id/name) and a textual complaint.

Data loader is not able to handle this and I found a suggestion to use Workbench instead. So I uploaded the file and set the proper fields. This is right before you start the actual upsert:

[image]

But when I click "Confirm Upsert", all records are rejected: "CaseNumber Not Specified, MISSING_ARGUMENT"

If I preview the CSV file, CaseNumber is filled with the data that I expect to see there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: is the number in your screenshot matching up with what you actually have for data in the excel (318 records)?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes.

Comment: By the way, I've submitted the PR, and I have a working demo available on my heroku if you want to try it and make sure it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to map by an autonumber field, which is read-only, so the mapping logic doesn't support what you're trying to do. This would work if you were working with a mappable field, such as custom External Id on cases, or a required name field (e.g. Account Name). However, it would be possible to patch workbench to support this, as it is [open source](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench), but you'd have to run your own local copy or submit a PR (Pull Request).

---

Edit: I have fixed the problem in my cloned copy, which you can try out [here](https://foxworkbench.herokuapp.com/). This clone may or may not be maintained or enhanced in the future, but I'll leave it up for as long as I can. There may be some delay on startup, as it is a Free Tier Heroku App. I have submitted a PR to have this put into the main app. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! In the meantime, I have solved my problem by using dataloader.io. It was not immediately apparent how to get it done with that product, but after consulting it's documentation, I got my data imported. Sorry for my impatience, but you know how it is. Thanks again!

Comment: @SanderdeJong No worries. You have a business to run. Still, I was able to make at least a minor contribution for anyone who might need this in the future.